# how to include all instance of g.ToList() to Value

Tags: c#

I have multiple instance of `g.ToList()`. I need to prepare a `lstResult` where I need to aggregate all instance of `g.ToList()`....g.ToList()[0], g.ToList()[1], etc.

how to do this?

```
 foreach (var g in data)
            {
                lstResult.Add(new Result
                {
                    Key = g.Key,
                    Values = g.ToList()[0].Value
                });
            }

  public class Result
   {
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: What is type of `g`?

Comment: If `g` is type of `Result` then `g.ToList()` will be `compilation error`.

Comment: "multiple instances of `g.ToList`"? Can you show what you mean? I can se only a single call to `g.ToList`. What does `g` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable.Select` should work for you:

```
foreach (var g in data)
{
    lstResult.Add(new Result
    {
        Key = g.Key,
        Values = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, I have updated my question. I follow your suggestion, but getting error

Comment: Well, your question is closed. I suggest you find a way to reword your question and include more information, such as the types for `g` and `data`. If you are getting an error with my code then I would surmise that `g.ToList()` would also throw an error.

Comment: Thanks  Jerry, please check new question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748668/how-to-merge-listvalue-and-remove-duplicates-for-name-class-pair-for-all-key