# How to merge `List<Value>` and remove duplicates for Name/class pair for all keys

Tags: c#

I have 2 list of `Result` with having list of `Value` and there are some duplicates Name/Class if we merge both Result list.

How to merge `List<Value>` and remove duplicates for Name/class pair for all keys?

```
var result1 = new List<Result>
    {
        new Result{Key = "X", Values = new List<Value>{new Value{Name = "A1", Class = "C1"}}},
        new Result{Key = "Y", Values = new List<Value>{new Value{Name = "B1", Class = "D1"}}}
    };

    var result2 = new List<Result>
    {
        new Result{Key = "X", Values = new List<Value>{new Value{Name = "A1", Class = "C1"}, new Value{Name = "A2", Class = "C1"}}},
        new Result{Key = "Y", Values = new List<Value>{new Value{Name = "B2", Class = "D2"}}}
    };
```

Here I tried,

```
    var lstResult = new List<Result>();

    var groups = result1.Concat(result2).GroupBy(a => a.Key);

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        lstResult.Add(new Result
        {
            Key = group.Key,
            Values = group.Select(x => x.Values).ToList()
        });
    }


 public class Result
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }
```

In above code I am getting error at line,

```
 Values = group.Select(x => x.Values).ToList() //error
```

> cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<net452.Program.Value>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<net452.Program.Value>'

Comment: Try `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

Comment: how to remove duplicates? For `X`, I cam 3 items where 2 are exact same Name/Class, I need one

Comment: I tried this ` Values = group.SelectMany(x => x.Values).Distinct().ToList()`, but duplicated not removed

Comment: Step one was the `SelectMany`, step two is implement `IEqualityComparer<Value>` and use that inside the `Distinct(new ValueComparer())`.

Comment: Another approach is shown in answers. In general, if you control the classes, you can implement Equals+GetHashCode (it's useful in many different places); otherwise, implement IEqualityComparer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to do this with linq. But you can try this function.

```
   List<Result> MergeList(List<Result>list1, List<Result>list2) {
        var myList = list1;
        foreach (var item in list2)
        {
            var obj = myList.Where(x => x.Key == item.Key).FirstOrDefault(); ;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                foreach (var vals in item.Values)
                {
                    if (!obj.Values.Any(x => x.Class == vals.Class && x.Name == vals.Name))
                    {
                        obj.Values.Add(vals);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works and has no duplicates. It is basically the same as Андрей Саяпин's answer however `GetHashCode` is overridden as well.

```
public class Result
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
        => other is Value o && Name == o.Name && Class == o.Class;

    public override int GetHashCode() => (Name, Class).GetHashCode();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result1 = new List<Result>
        {
            new Result{Key = "X", Values = new List<Value>{
                new Value{Name = "A1", Class = "C1"}}},

            new Result{Key = "Y", Values = new List<Value>{
                new Value{Name = "B1", Class = "D1"}}}
        };

        var result2 = new List<Result>
        {
            new Result{Key = "X", Values = new List<Value>{
                new Value{Name = "A1", Class = "C1"},
                new Value{Name = "A2", Class = "C1"}}},

            new Result{Key = "Y", Values = new List<Value>{
                new Value{Name = "B2", Class = "D2"}}}
        };

        var lstResult = new List<Result>();

        var groups = result1.Concat(result2).GroupBy(a => a.Key);

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            lstResult.Add(new Result()
            {
                Key = group.Key,
                Values = group.SelectMany(x => x.Values).Distinct().ToList()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly, Distinct uses hash code to quickly check if items should be compared

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `Equals` for `Value` class, you can do it the way you do now, with this addition:

```
Values = group.SelectMany(x => x.Values).Distinct().ToList()
```

If `Value` class is immutable, that's safe to do, and will look like

```
class Value {
    public override bool Equals(object other) => other is Value v && v.Name == Name && v.Class == Class;
}
```

As stated [in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1), default equality comparer is used to determine if items differ

BTW, you can make `Value` a struct and get properly working `Distinct` free of charge (because of equality comparison semantics for value types)

Comment: Thanks, I applied Equals, but it's even not removing duplicates

Comment: The new `record` gives you working Distinct as well, if you prefer to have a reference and also gives you immutability.